# How to check if ureadahead functioning

Tags: bootchart, ureadahead

I got spinning 5400 rpm 1Gb drive.

Booting takes **69 seconds** (is it slow?) and `/var/lib/ureadahead` contains empty directory `debugfs`. That is why I wonder if ureadahead does its job.

`/var` directory is on root partition

```
~ > df
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7        24G   15G  8,1G  65% /
udev            3,9G  4,0K  3,9G   1% /dev
/dev/sda9       705G  143G  562G  21% /data
/dev/sda8        29G   24G  4,2G  85% /home
```

configs seem to be default

```
~ > cat /etc/init/ureadahead.conf|grep -v '#'|grep -ve '^$'
description "Read required files in advance"
start on starting mountall
stop on stopped rc
expect fork
kill timeout 180
normal exit 0
exec /sbin/ureadahead --daemon
pre-stop exec sleep 45

~ > cat /etc/init/ureadahead-other.conf|grep -v '#'|grep -ve '^$'
description "Read required files in advance (for other mountpoints)"
start on mounted DEVICE=[/UL]* MOUNTPOINT=/?*
expect fork
normal exit 0 4
exec /sbin/ureadahead --daemon $MOUNTPOINT
```

Strangily /var/log/upstart/ureadahead.log.1.gz contains almost only "Ignored relative path" or "No such file or directory" tagged entries.

```
root:/var/log# zcat upstart/ureadahead.log.1.gz |grep -v "Ignored relative path"
Counted 4 CPUs

ureadahead:/data/swapfile: Error retrieving chunk extents: Operation not supported
ureadahead:/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-eth0.conf: No such file or directory
ureadahead:/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlan0.conf: No such file or directory
ureadahead:/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-eth0.conf: No such file or directory
ureadahead:/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlan0.conf: No such file or directory
ureadahead:/etc/X11/xorg.conf: No such file or directory
ureadahead:/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-eth0.conf: No such file or directory
ureadahead:/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlan0.conf: No such file or directory
ureadahead:/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-eth0.conf: No such file or directory
ureadahead:/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlan0.conf: No such file or directory
ureadahead:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf: No such file or directory
Counted 4 CPUs

ureadahead:/data/swapfile: Error retrieving chunk extents: Operation not supported
```

On bootchart ureadahead appears on **16**th second and lasts less than a second. Compare to https://superuser.com/questions/286571/ubuntu-slow-startup-time-modprobe where ureadahead starts immediately after plymouthd

[image: bootchart.jpg]

**UPDATE 1** Add blockdev report

```
# blockdev --report
RO    RA   SSZ   BSZ   StartSec            Size   Device
rw   256   512  4096          0   1000204886016   /dev/sda
rw   256   512  4096       2048       524288000   /dev/sda1
rw   256   512  4096    1026048        41943040   /dev/sda2
rw   256   512  4096    1107968       134217728   /dev/sda3
rw   256   512  4096    1370112       524288000   /dev/sda4
rw   256   512  4096    2394112    171795546112   /dev/sda5
rw   256   512  4096 1927233536     13460267008   /dev/sda6
rw   256   512  4096  337932288     26214400000   /dev/sda7
rw   256   512  4096  389132288     31457280000   /dev/sda8
rw   256   512  4096  450572288    756050558976   /dev/sda9
rw   256   512   512          0      1073741312   /dev/sr0
```

Partitions /dev/sda1 - /dev/sda/6 are windoze, ESP, DIAGS, WINRETOOLS, PBR Image

Comment: I ended up disabling the service: `sudo systemctl disable ureadahead.service`. This is Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4

Comment: can you provide your dmesg output?

Answer (score 2):

This version of ureadahead has been around since at least the start of 2015 and I doubt it was written with systemd in mind. I don't know what bumped the minor versions but last commits [are from 2010](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~canonical-scott/ureadahead/trunk/files). They probably included some of the merge requests since your version is [reporting cpu count](https://code.launchpad.net/~timg-tpi/ureadahead/LP491943/+merge/33251%20).

[The dev](https://www.linkedin.com/in/keybuk) is now working for Google.

Your best bet at this point would be to keep it disabled. If looking to shave off a couple seconds off boot, remove wpa_supplicant if not needed.

Comment: Ubuntu has given up on ureadahead as of cosmic. Just "apt purge utreadahad: and be happy,